# Logon failed. Error in File xx.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, authentication, exception, crystal-reports

WPF Client application connect to a database in the server. Client pc does not have MS sql server installed. So i installed sql server native client latest version in the Client PC. But when i attempt to view the report i got the following error message. i double checked the database connection string in app.config,it contains correct logon information.

```
<message>Logon failed.Error in File EmployeeMealSummary {B32AECDC-7F60-4BD9-B2C9-F8153BF2CB5A}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.</message>   
<source>rptcontrollers.dll</source>
<stackTrace>at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.SetTableLocation(ISCRTable CurTable, ISCRTable NewTable)
```

at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.set_Location(String value)

I have attached the code. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument     reportDocument)
{
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo;
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables crTables = _report.Database.Tables;

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
    {
        crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Clear();
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Clear();
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = null;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connectionInfo.ServerName;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connectionInfo.UserID;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connectionInfo.Password;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connectionInfo.DatabaseName;
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);

        if (crTable.Name == "vEmployee" || crTable.Name == "TB_USER_DEPT" )
        {
            CenUtility.ErrorLog.CreateLog(new ArrayTypeMismatchException());
            crTable.Location = connectionInfo.DatabaseName + ".dbo." + crTable.Location; 
        }
        else
        {
            crTable.Location = connectionInfo.DatabaseName + ".CafDB." + crTable.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i set location the database and update the tables 
check that you are passed the right(DatabaseName, Password, UserId , ServerName)
try this way and tell me if it work in the right way or not

Comment: you should check the parameter , parameter in C# need the same name of parameter in crystal , and check the type ,if you passed a date passed them as string